# C# WInForm - Combo Box relying on another combo box.. is it possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have been trying to connect (make it dependent) to another combo box but no success at all.

For example I have 2 items for ComboBox1. These would be A and B. Now each item should have a default(another) Combo Box. Like ComboBox1 item A has a ComboBox2 with 3 items and ComboBox1 item B has a ComboBox2 with 2 items. These changes upon the selectIndexChange of each item in ComboBox1. So when ComboBox1 changes value the ComboBox2 refreshes(update) its contents.

Any ideas how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: First look for Information in stackoverflow and than make your asking clear and post some code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel while a little bit jargon, the question is really understandable. I don't think this kind of comments could be productive in this society.

Comment: @EhsanAbd If so then pls take a look at number of close votes this question has received! If you have access to view close votes

Comment: I guess what you are trying is having a comboBox as an comboBoxItem for another comboBox. Is it?

Comment: yes Samarth .. ComboBox2 relies on ComboBox1 .. when a selectedIndex changes at ComboBox1 then the ComboBox2 refreshes.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the comboBox events and find one like value changed.

Then, inside the event put this.

```
CombBox c = sender as ComboBox;
switch(c.Name)
{
  case " comboBox1":
      //do stuff with combobox2
   break;
}
```

You can adjust it to your liking.